# Как удалить дубликаты?

Tags: php

Имеется переменная в которой некоторый список e-mail'ов как удалить дубликаты?

Answer (score 3):

```
$emails = array('mail@foo.com', ...);
$emails = array_unique($emails);
```

Comment: `Vasia@mail.ru`  и  `vasia@Mail.ru`  посчитаются разными адресами в этом случае, т.к. case учитывается. См. [комментарии к документации](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), там есть решение, нечувствительное к регистру.

Более сложный случай, когда `vassia@gmail.com`, `v.a.s.s.i.a@gmail.com` и `vassia+spam@gmail.com` это один и тот же ящик — не рассматриваем.

Comment: Более сложный случай, когда vassia@gmail.com, v.a.s.s.i.a@gmail.com и vassia+spam@gmail.com это один и тот же ящик — не рассматриваем.

Ага, так же не рассматриваем случай, когда круг и квадрат - одна и та же геометрическая фигура))

Comment: а они суть одно и то же! [доказательство](http://www.lolblog.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/1290616506315.jpg) ; )

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант уникализации емейлов, без учета регистра

```
$emails = array(
'vasya@gmail.com', 'Vasya@Gmail.COM', 'Petya@mail.ru', 'PETYA@MAIL.RU', 'sasha@ya.ru', 'medik@rambler.ru'
);

$emails = array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $emails));

var_dump($emails);
```

Выведет:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "vasya@gmail.com"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "petya@mail.ru"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "sasha@ya.ru"
  [5]=>
  string(16) "medik@rambler.ru"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Использовать значение в качестве ключа массива.

```
$a = explode(';', $emailstr);

$u = array();
for($a as $v)
   $u[$a] = $a;

$emailstr = implode(';', $u);
```

Comment: Кстати, неочевидное решение.